# How do I center a couple of items and append the rest to the right?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a couple of items that I want to be centered in a row and then I have a couple more items that I want to be on the right of centered ones, but not in the far right. Here is a picture:

[image]

So the container of the 3 in the middle should be centered actually. Would also need all of them to be centered vertically. Ideas?

Comment: share your code

Comment: Did you consider using dummy items?

Comment: @TemaniAfif dude i see you every where  :)) youre the next jon skeet

Comment: @RaheleDadmand why not ;)

Comment: I cannot share the code, but i have tried flex-box and came to the conclusion it is not possible. Not much of a css guy though. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with flexbox, here is an example where you can use a hidden element to create this layout:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding:10px 0;
  
  /*To illutrate the center*/
  background:linear-gradient(to right,transparent calc(50% - 4px),#000 0,#000 calc(50% + 4px),transparent calc(50% + 4px));
}


.el {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  width:calc( (3 * 40px) + (6 * 4px) ); /* width of 3 element + their margin*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>

  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
</div>
```

And if the element on the right are unknown you can use more container:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding:20px 0;
  
  /*To illutrate the center*/
  background:linear-gradient(to right,transparent calc(50% - 4px),#000 0,#000 calc(50% + 4px),transparent calc(50% + 4px));
}

.container>div:not(.center) {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
}

.el {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  margin-right:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!! Didn't know i could utilize this before selector.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can join first three elements into div and center it with any method you prefer, join second group and make it first group's child, positioned absolutely. So it will not affect centering of first group. Then translate second group to the right. Here's example with flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  margin: 16px;
}

.absolute {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="absolute">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25hvqyjm/6/) that i prepared for you.

Explaination:
For the center div, use margin auto but you have to give it a width, this way it will be centered. For the div on the right, use display inline in order to convert the element to inline element instead of block element, then add some margin to the left form the centered div.

```css
.middleDiv{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.onRight{
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="middleDiv">
        <span>el1</span>
        <span>el2</span>
        <span>el3</span>
        <div class="onRight">
            <span>on the right</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the elements are not centred